# Ionic 4 - How to change font-size of button inside a Toast

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic4

I'm building an app with **Ionic 4** + React.

Using a **toast component** when the user delete an element to show the message "deleted successfully", but adding a **button inside** to give the possibility to undo the action.

I need to change the font-size of that button, but almost all the toast DOM is inside a `shadow-root`:

[image]

Reading articles [like this](https://www.joshmorony.com/shadow-dom-usage-in-ionic-web-components/), I understand that everything inside `shadow-root` it can't be styled by css selectors and must be styled using CSS4 Ionic variables.

But I can't find a css variable to change de font-size of the button, this is what Ionic does (not with variables):

[image]

Read some people that said that could work with a custom class, I already tried that but without any luck:

**Toast component:**

```
<IonToast
  cssClass="e7-toast"
  isOpen={showToastDeshacer}
  color="dark"
  onDidDismiss={() => setShowToastDeshacer(false)}
  message="Deleted successfully"
  position="bottom"
  buttons={[
    {
      text: 'Undo',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Undo clicked');
      }
    }
  ]}
/>
```

**CSS:**

```
.e7-toast .toast-button-inner {
  font-size: 44px!important;
}
```

Anyone with more experience in Ionic 4 knows a way to change the font-size of that button?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to do it from global.scss , ion-toast div.toast-wrapper div.toast-button-group button.toast-button { font-size: 18px } , try it in this way.

Comment: @MostafaHarb I'm not using sass (by default with cli doesn't created any sass), where should a place the global.scss (or css)? I can't find doc about this, I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

you can change the shadow dom by using `::part`.
There is the article for your reference:
https://css-tricks.com/styling-in-the-shadow-dom-with-css-shadow-parts/